# Java IO Server Client read and process users input

Tags: java, client-server, java-io

I have a simple Fileserver and Client (code from the web) that let me send files to my other laptop inside my home LAN. Now, the file sent from the server to the client is hardcoded but i want to prompt user at client-side to input a filename, send it to the server and send back the specified file. My code looks like this:

**Server**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedOutputStream outputStream;
        BufferedInputStream inputStream;
        FileInputStream fileInput;

        String file = "C:/java/file.mp4";

        try {

            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12345); 

            while(true) { 

                Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();

                outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);

                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);

                int packetToSend = -1;

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                while((packetToSend = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) { 

                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, packetToSend);
                    System.out.println("sending " + packetToSend + " bytes");
                    outputStream.flush();

                }

            }

        }

        catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

And thats the Client Code (IPAdress of the Server is argument s[0] and the path to save the file is s[1] in main method.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] s) {

        try { 

            String address = new String(s[0]);
            String fileToSave = new String(s[1]); 
            Socket socket = new Socket(address,12345);

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave);

            int n;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

            System.out.println("Connected");    

            while ((n = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                System.out.println("received "+n+" bytes");
                fos.write(buffer, 0, n);

                fos.flush();

            }

            System.out.println("recieved");

        }

        catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

I want to promt the user on client side to input a filename after client is connected to send to the server and the server should send that file.

i tried to put this in client side after `System.out.println("connected");`

```
System.out.print("Insert filename to download: ");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String input = null;

    try {

       input = reader.readLine();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

       System.out.println("Eingabe konnte nicht verarbeitet werden!");
       System.exit(1);

    }

    System.out.println("Eingabe: " + input);
```

and on server side i put this after `outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());` to override the hardcoded filename at the beginning of server class.

```
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputStream);

        fileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
```

Once a connection is established, client side is idle (cant input something) and server side does nothing after writing out to console "new connection".

how can i solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client sends to the server the filename.  So first you must extract the filename from the socket's input stream.  To do that you need to establish a protocol for how information will be sent.  This is critical when dealing with TCP streams, which is different from UDP datagrams.  Typically two newlines is used to convey the end of a message.  But because it is not normal for a filename to have a newline in it, we will use one newline to convey end of message.

We can then use Scanner to extract the filename from the client's socket.

```
String fileName;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (clientSocket.getInputStream());
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    fileName = scanner.nextLine();
    break;
}
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
fileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
```

In this example the fileName must be the absolute path to that file as its sits in the server's file system.  In future versions you might want to use a directory on the server where files are stored and the client can give you the relative path to file from that directory.  Here is how that would look like.

```
String fileName;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (clientSocket.getInputStream());
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    fileName = scanner.nextLine();
    break;
}
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE_DIR + fileName);
fileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
```

The variable FILE_DIR would look something like:

```
static String FILE_DIR = "C:/java/";
```

And the file that the client would send over would just be `file.mp4`

EDIT 1:

Here is the Client code with the recommendations.  Please note that this test quality code, not production code.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {

    static String FILE_DIR = "./";

    public static void main(String[] s) throws IOException {

        /**
         * Establish socket using main args.
         */
        String address = s[0];

        while (true) {

            /**
             * Get the file name from the user.
             */
            System.out.print("Insert filename to download: ");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String fileName = null;
            try {
                fileName = reader.readLine();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Eingabe konnte nicht verarbeitet werden!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("Eingabe: " + fileName);

            /**
             * Create the socket.
             */
            Socket socket = new Socket(address, 12345);

            /**
             * With file name in hand, proceed to send the filename to the
             * server.
             */
            //...put in try-with-resources to close the outputstream.
            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                System.out.println("Connected:  Sending file name to server.");
                //...send file name plus a newline.
                bos.write((fileName + '\n').getBytes());
                bos.flush();

            /**
             * Get the file contents and save to disk.
             */
            //...wrap input stream in DataInpuStream for portability.
            //...put in try-with-resource to close the input stream.
            try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                int n;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                System.out.println("Connected:  Recieving file contents from server.");
                while ((n = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("received " + n + " bytes");
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
                    fos.flush();
                }
                System.out.println("recieved");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     }
    }
}
```

and here's the server code.  Please note the server is retrieving the file from local directory called ./files/, please change that to whatever directory you want.

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server {

```
static String FILE_DIR = "./files/";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedInputStream inputStream;
    FileInputStream fileInput;

    try {

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(12345);

        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = socket.accept();

            /**
             * Get the file name from the client. File name is one per line.
             */
            //...put in trye-with-resources to close InputStream for us.
            try (InputStream inputFromClient = clientSocket.getInputStream()) {
                System.out.println("Connected:  Getting file name from client.");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFromClient);
                String fileName;
                if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    fileName = scanner.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("File name = " + fileName);
                } else {
                    //...no line found, continue.  consider logging an error or warning.
                    continue;
                }

                /**
                 * With fileName in hand, we can proceed to send the
                 * contents of the file to the client.
                 */
                fileInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                //...use DataInputStream for more portable code
                DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(fileInput);
                inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(dataInput);
                int packetToSend = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                //...consider closing the OutputStream to let the client know.
                //...use try-with-resource to close the outputStream for us.
                //...wrap your outputStream in DataOutputStream
                try (BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()))) {
                    while ((packetToSend = inputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, packetToSend);
                        System.out.println("sending " + packetToSend + " bytes");
                        outputStream.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: sry i think you dismatched my question. i dont want to send the file from client to server, i want to connect to the server - after connection a prompt should appear on client side to input a filename. this filename should be sent to the server and finally, the server should return the specified file. so i guess i have to add the scanner in server side after socket.accept(), right? but how to input the filename after connection is established and send it to the server?

Comment: I understood the question.  The client is sending just the fileName to the server.  The scanner is to get just the fileName.  I think its the only part of your implementation that might be wrong.  In your implementation the server takes the InputStream from the socket and uses it for the input to the FileInputStream.  This is where the problem is.  The FileInputStream requires the file path (what we been calling fileName) as input.  So extract the fileName from the socket's InputStream first, then pass just the fileName to the FileInputStream.

Comment: I'm going to EDIT my answer with the full client and server code.

Comment: Thats why i close the socket (via closing the outputSteam) on the server.  That would signal the client that the file is completely sent.  Normally in tcp streams there are delimitters but because this is raw data checking for a delimitter (like two newlines) is not desirable because it might show up as part of the file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, the command now arrives the server but after that i got an exception in client code ´java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed at java.net.Socket.getInputStream(Unknown Source) at Client.main(client.java:53)´ but the client runs after that and write again "Insert filename to download"

Comment: I'll runt he code over here and try to reporduce.  Quick question, just make sure you are using my last editted version, where on the server I moved out the closing bracket of the first try with resources to the end of the loop.

Comment: sry i edited my comment but 5 min was gone.. i run it as standalone and after sending 5 packets i got an "connection reset by peer: socket.write error" on serverside and a socket is closed error on client side.. once i got an "software caused connection abort: socket write error" on server

Comment: Sorry about that.  The problem is that the try-with-resources on the Client's outputstream is closing the socket prematurely.  I moved the closing bracket on that try block to the end.  Now the socket will remain open until the file's contents are transmitted.

Comment: wow, thanks now its working exactly as i wanted. but can you please explain me what "put in try-with-resources to close the outputstream"  in comment on that try block means? actually i added to your code after System.out.println("received"); the line fos.close(); to close the outputstream. is that ok?

Comment: If you close any stream that you get from a socket then the socket will close.  The reason I want to close the socket is to signal the end of the file and also to not accidentally leave streams/sockets open (instinctively i get scared when i dont see streams being closed).  My first attempts had me closing the streams a little to early, which caused the edits to the code.  Essentially now he code is openning a stream, then another one, then closing both.  THat happens on both the client and server.

Comment: so after filetransfer i should call inputStream.close() and outputStream.close() on both sides, am i right? i tried but get an error cannot find symol outputStream.close() in server

Comment: Try with resources closes them for us.  Basically it promises to close it at the end of try block, even if an exception is called.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: very nice, thank you. one more question, if you can answer. is there a trick to count the approximate transfer rate of the socket connection?